# Microsoft Graph API slow Response

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api, o365-flow

I am very new to MS Graph API & o365 python library and I am using Graph API & o365 library to fetch various email messages information, Such as email sender name, email received time, email body information, attachment details, etc.
• I am facing a latency in the response on given below code partI am attaching the part where Graph API response is slow,

```
finalConvId = "XXXXXX" # Conversation ID 
query = mailbox.new_query().on_attribute('conversation_id').equals(finalConvId)
mailbox.get_messages(limit=100, query=query, batch=20, download_attachments=False)
```

Would you please help me with this.
Thanks in advance for your precious time.

Comment: You should be careful when you deal while accessing good amount of info (such as accessing email messages) with Microsoft Graph API. Instead of accessing bulk data, you should consider using pagination. In your scenario, when you make the above call against Microsoft Graph return multiple pages of data either due to server-side paging or due to the use of the $top query parameter to specifically limit the page size in a request. When a result set spans multiple pages, Microsoft Graph returns an @odata.nextLink property in the response that contains a URL to the next page of results.

Comment: For example, the following URL requests all the users in an organization with a page size of 5, specified with the $top query parameter: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=5
If the result contains more than five users, Microsoft Graph will return an @odata.nextLink property with the first page of users.

Paging is a best practice while using Microsoft Graph API. Here's the [documentation for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging)!!

Comment: Does it helped?

Comment: Currently working on this. will let you know Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure, let me know how it goes...!!